# Eclipse icon meaning and how to resolve them

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

What do these eclipse icons mean and how to resolve them, if there is an issue?
I think is some how contributing to the errors Im getting during compile/build using "mvn test" command (from where pom.xml file is.
Btw, I'm relatively new to Java/Maven and this is my full scale project (selenium automation)

[image: Eclipse project screenshot]

Comment: Having two `JRE System Library` nodes is incorrect and can be fixed in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_. The `?` labels are from version control (Git?) and mean that those files have not yet been added or ignored.

Comment: Great thanks. I removed the extra jre.

Comment: @howlger Ignored files have a "no parking" overlay, don't they?

Comment: @GeroldBroser In EGit and in Subversive ignored files have no overlay (in preferences, search for `Label`). Since there is no `[<repo> <branch>]` shown at the project node, I doubt it's Git.

Comment: @howlger You're right. I ignored a `.cmd` and on my Laptop screen it seemed that there is something light-gray in the bottom-right corner. On a newly created `.txt` there's nothing. Thanks, BTW, for the Label info. I didn't know that page yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

? on the file means there are changes in those files when compared with the version on the repository. What is the exact error you see during build?

Comment: The issue and explanantion on the project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914058/running-from-command-line-using-mvn-test-gives-error-where-dependency-jar-is-n

Comment: The '**?**' means that these files aren't under SCM control yet (a.k.a. _untracked_). Dirty files are indicated by a '**>**' between the icon and the name.

Answer (score 1):

According to *howlger*'s comment to the question see:

- *Window* → *Preferences* → *Version Control (Team)* → e.g. *Git* → *Label Decorations*:

  [image: Eclipse Label Decorations]

Comment: Thanks. This is also very helpful.